# <tr> tag not making new row in html

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I was making a dummy form page but my  tag is not working, it puts everything in one row. Why is it so?  Also placeholders in my drop down menu doesn't seem to be working, I want to show a text that says "day" "month" "year" when birthday section appear on screen. Thanks in advance
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <label for="firstName"><b> First Name: <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" required></b></label>
        <label for="lastName"><b> Last Name: <input id="lastname"type="text" name="lastName" required></b></label>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <label for="male"><b>Male <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender"></b></label>
        <label for="female"><b>Female <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender"></b></label>
        <label for="other"><b>Other <input id="other" type="radio" name="gender"></b></label>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <label for="email"><b> Email: <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required></b></label>
        <label for="password"><b> Password: <input id="password"type="password" name="password" minlength="5" maxlength="10" placeholder="password" required></b></label>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <label>Birthday:</label>
        <select name="day" placeholder="day">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
          <option>7</option>
          <option>8</option>
        </select>
        <select name="month" placeholder="month">
          <option>jan</option>
          <option>feb</option>
          <option>mar</option>
          <option>apr</option>
          <option>may</option>
          <option>jun</option>
          <option>jul</option>
          <option>aug</option>
        </select>
        <select name="year" placeholder="year">
          <option>1992</option>
          <option>1882</option>
          <option>1986</option>
          <option>2016</option>
          <option>2009</option>
          <option>1973</option>
          <option>1642</option>
          <option>1558</option>
        </select>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        Agree to this text
        <input type="checkbox" name="Agree" required>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <button>Go</button>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The correct structure of a `TABLE` is `<table> <tr> <td></td> </tr> </table>` . You are missing the `td's`

Comment: `table row` expects `table data` fields. Try putting your labels in a `td`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp

Comment: You need to use `<td>` tags as well. Your HTML is invalid, so you will get weird results. Now with that said, don't use tables for lay out. It is **very** outdated.

Comment: Use literally anything else other than table: https://jsfiddle.net/4w1ak9cL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having invalid html markup for `<table>`, the `<td>` tag within each row is mandatory.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="firstName"><b> First Name:  <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" required></b></label>
          <label for="lastName"><b> Last Name:    <input id="lastname"type="text" name="lastName" required></b></label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="male"><b>Male <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender"></b></label>
          <label for="female"><b>Female <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender"></b></label>
          <label for="other"><b>Other <input id="other" type="radio" name="gender"></b></label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="email"><b> Email:   <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required></b></label>
          <label for="password"><b> Password: <input id="password"type="password" name="password" minlength="5" maxlength="10" placeholder="password" required></b></label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Birthday:</label>
          <select name="day" placeholder="day">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
          </select>
          <select name="month" placeholder="month">
            <option>jan</option>
            <option>feb</option>
            <option>mar</option>
            <option>apr</option>
            <option>may</option>
            <option>jun</option>
            <option>jul</option>
            <option>aug</option>
          </select>
          <select name="year" placeholder="year">
            <option>1992</option>
            <option>1882</option>
            <option>1986</option>
            <option>2016</option>
            <option>2009</option>
            <option>1973</option>
            <option>1642</option>
            <option>1558</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Agree to this text
          <input type="checkbox" name="Agree" required>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button>Go</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```